# Viber-like "Incoming Call" Dialog for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio, background-process, voip

I am developing a VoIP iOS app (using Twilio) that has background permissions. So I set up the app to keep listening for incoming connections.

After I receive a connection, I would like to display to the user a customized dialog to answer or reject the call (it could be a UIViewController or anything that can achieve this).

I have been suggested UILocalNotifications , but those can only display information related to the app, and do not allow the user to open the app. Push notifications have the same functionality.

So how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

I've only seen this done with UILocalNotifications in the way my good friend Devin outlines in [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/a-swift-adventure-building-basicphone-with-twilioclient-part-2.html). It won't let the user accept/reject from the notification but will open the app for them if they click it. The key code that makes it happen, in Swift, is this:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState != UIApplicationState.Active {
    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Incoming Call"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
}
```

Know it's not the exact solution you're looking for but hope it helps you or someone else who stumbles on this question.